# Class function template definition outside of the class

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

So i've been coding my own unique_ptr class and i have to handle arrays in a different way that i handle other types.

```cpp
template <typename TYPE, bool _arr = std::is_array<TYPE>::value>
    class scoped_ptr final {
    private:
        typedef std::remove_extent_t<TYPE> gen;
        gen* m_data;
    public:
        //some methods
        void reset();
    };

template<typename TYPE ,bool _arr>
    inline void scoped_ptr<TYPE, _arr>::reset()
    {
    //some code...
    }
```

The problem is that i want the reset method to only be avaiable to non array allocations, when using std::enable_if i get the error: "A default template argument cannot be specified on the declaration of a member of a class template outside of its class" despite the code still compiling

```cpp
template<typename TYPE ,bool _arr>
    class scoped_ptr final {
    public:
        template<typename = typename std::enable_if<!_arr>::type>
        void reset();
    };

template<typename TYPE ,bool _arr>
template<typename = typename std::enable_if<!_arr>::type>
    inline void scoped_ptr<TYPE, _arr>::reset()
    {
    }
```

I also tryed this, but it also gives an error: "template argument list must match parameter list"

```cpp
template<typename TYPE ,bool _arr>
    inline void scoped_ptr<TYPE, false>::reset()
    {
    }
```

Does anybody have an idea on how can i disable this method for arrays? I know i could specialize the class scoped_ptr but i wanted to avoid code duplication. Is there any way to do it?

**Edit:**

After reading the responses i changed the code to this:

```cpp
template <typename TYPE, bool is_arr = std::is_array<TYPE>::value>
    class scoped_ptr final {
    private:
        typedef std::remove_extent_t<TYPE> gen;
        gen* m_data;

    public:
        //Some methods

        template<bool _arr = is_arr, typename = typename std::enable_if<!_arr>::type>
        void reset();

    };


    template<typename TYPE, bool is_arr>
    template<bool, typename>
    inline void scoped_ptr<TYPE, is_arr>::reset()
    {
    }
```

The code compiles with no errors, until i try to call the method:

```cpp
int main() {

    scoped_ptr<int> ptr = new int;
    ptr.reset();
}
```

Thats when i get the error: "void scoped_ptr«int,false»::reset(void): could not deduce template argument for «unnamed-symbol»"

But if i write the implementation inside of the class the error goes away. How can i fix this?

Comment: Try to replace `template<bool, typename>` with `template<bool _arr, typename>`. Looks like a bug in Microsoft compiler.

Comment: Wow that helped a lot thx for everything, i also should have noted that im working with Visual Studio 19. Does that bug always happen in this context? What should i be on the lookout for?

Comment: These bugs are very unpredictable and there is no universal recipe how to avoid them and how to fix them. When it comes to templates, I've seen many of them in MSVC. I'd suggest to try another compiler (e.g. gcc - see [example](https://godbolt.org/z/g-HdUE)) and if it compiles the code, fiddle around with it to make it work with MSVC. Adding a redundant parameter name was a pure guess on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make `reset()` SFINAE-friendly, make it a fake template:

```
template<bool is_arr = _arr, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_arr>>
void reset();
```

Note that SFINAE works when a template is instantiated, and the condition should depend on the template parameter. This is not a valid SFINAE construct:

```
template<typename = typename std::enable_if<!_arr>::type>
void reset();
```

If you don't care about SFINAE-friendliness, use `static_assert()` inside `reset()`.

**Edit**.

Consider the following [simple code](https://godbolt.org/z/a2AMvy) as a demonstration of valid and invalid SFINAE:

```
template<class T, bool f = std::is_integral_v<T>>
struct S {
    // template<typename = std::enable_if_t<f>>                 // (invalid)
    template<bool _f = f, typename = std::enable_if_t<_f>>      // (valid)
    void reset() {}
};

template<class T, typename = void>
struct has_reset : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct has_reset<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().reset())>> : std::true_type {};

void foo() {
    has_reset<S<int>>::value;
    has_reset<S<void>>::value;
}
```

It will fail to compile if your replace the `(valid)` line with the `(invalid)` one.

**Edit 2.**

When you define a member function outside the class, you don't repeat default values of template parameters:

```
template<class T, bool f>
template<bool, typename>
void S<T, f>::reset() { }
```

**Edit 3.**

For some reason (a compiler bug I suppose) MSVC rejects this definition with the error: "Could not deduce template argument for «unnamed-symbol»". It can be fixed by adding a name for the `bool` parameter:

```
template<class T, bool f>
template<bool _f, typename>
void S<T, f>::reset() { }
```

This name should match that in the declaration.

Comment: So when should i use fake templates? With std::enable_if or does any other function in type_traits that requires it? Also doesnt that template argument gets evaluated at the same time as the class template arguments?

Comment: @uneven_mark, I updated my answer and confirm that OP's SFINAE is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I realized it as well.

Comment: @Denomycor, you use fake templates when you need SFINAE. SFINAE works only when a template is instantiated, only if the condition depends on the template parameter and only if the error happens right here (immediate context). `enable_if` is a canonical template to implement SFINAE, but it can be implemented without it, too.

Comment: @Denomycor, BTW, `has_reset` is implemented using SFINAE.

Comment: Right, ok ty guys, but now std::enable_if can not deduce the argument types and fails to compile when i call the function

Comment: @Denomycor, check your code, if you can't find the error, edit your question, and add new code. But don't remove the old code, please.